# C/C++ Automatic Code Optimization

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, clang, llvm

I would like to optimize a C/C++ code and get the optimized version in C or an intermediate representation (like LLVM IR), without actually compiling the code, mainly because of missing dependencies. In other words, I am looking for a way to see the results of optimization on specific pieces of C code, assuming that any compiler will not compile the code because of missing libraries and dependencies.

Is there any way to leverage optimization techniques built into open-source C/C++ compilers (like GCC and Clang) without compiling the code? I am mainly interested in the Control Flow Graph (CFG) of the functions after optimization. I am fully aware of the fact that this won't be totally possible, and almost certainly produces different results compared to when dependencies are present (due to inlining, for instance).

Comment: It's possible to compile C/C++ code without linking (`-c` option). And GCC's `-fdump-tree-all` option will print intermediate representation (GIMPLE) after all optimization stages.

Comment: I usually like to look at the generated assembly code for this.  At least for GCC, simply pass the `-S` switch.  Since this will stop the compilation process before the linking stage, all you need are the declarations of your external dependencies.  Note however, that link-time optimization might still change the final executable.

Comment: Suppose you define "density" of code as dividing the absolute minimum time it could possibly take by the time it actually takes. In my experience, small programs are often fairly dense - there is not huge room for speedup. But in large realistic software the density can be very low, with orders of magnitude room for speedup. Optimizing compilers can give you small speedup factors, but not large. Large speedups are only found through human intelligence. So which kind of software are you talking about - small or large?